# How to verify if BQ Load was successful?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a scheduled python script which `downloads some data and uploads into a bq table` on hourly basis. The script internally uses `bq load` command to load the data into BQ. I have noticed that sometimes bq load fails ( often partial data loaded / and sometimes the entire load operation fails). I cannot afford data loss here so I want to build a retry solution which will retry the `download and bq load operation` for the missed period. In order to get the information about the data that is successfully loaded, I am currently querying the BQ table to get the max timestamp.

Let's understand with an example here:-

Script successfully runs at 9:00 AM to collect data from 8:00 AM to 9:00 AM. Now the BQ table will have `start_timestamp` column as 8:00 AM and `end_timestamp` column as 9:00 AM. Here, if I query the BQ table for max timestamp after the run is complete, I will get 9:00 AM which is correct since the data got loaded.

Now my question :

`Is there any better way of certainly verifying that the bq load was successful other than the above way ?`

One solution which I think could be useful but I am not very sure is using the `bq show` command to get the status of a BQ job using the BQ Job ID. But with this approach I doubt if a SUCCESS status in bq show command guarantees that the data got loaded into BQ table.

Would really appreciate your thoughts on this!

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways to verify BQ Load job success or not is by checking the job status. You can create your own [job id](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-jobs#generate-jobid)  for a load job. You can use this Job id to load data. By using this job id you can verify [job status](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#viewing_information_about_jobs) PENDING, RUNNING and DONE.

Comment: I tried this approach also but somehow `bq show --job=true myproject:US.bquijob_123x456_123y123z123c` this command is giving "BQ error, Job not found" Surprisingly, this happens only for the jobs that were successfull. For the failed jobs, it returns the expected JSON with all the information.

Comment: @xvzf For the job not found error, I would suggest adding the [flag](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#view_job_details_2) --location=LOCATION, where LOCATION is the location where the job runs. Let me know if adding the location flag solved your issue.